# how to render form and accept values in the same function python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Is there any way in flask where I can render the form and at the click of the submit button fetch values.
The error I am getting is 404 not found and I don't know why. Is there any better way to do this.

```
@application.route('/cargohandled',methods=['POST'])
def cargohandled():
    if request.method == 'post':
        postman = request.form['postman']
        postype = request.form['postype']
        return {'postman' : postman, 'postype': postype}
    else:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT `PortName` From trarep")
        portname = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT `PortType` From trarep")
        porttype = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('cargo_handled.htm.j2',title = 'Cargo Handled',portname = portname,porttype= porttype)
    return "CG"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow both GET and POST.
And you should capitalise "post" in your `if` clause.

You can do away with the `else:` clause since the rest of the function will execute if the `request.method != 'POST'`.

The final `return` would never get executed so you can leave that out too.

```
@application.route('/cargohandled',methods=['GET','POST'])
def cargohandled():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postman = request.form['postman']
        postype = request.form['postype']
        return {'postman' : postman, 'postype': postype}
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT `PortName` From trarep")
    portname = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT `PortType` From trarep")
    porttype = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('cargo_handled.htm.j2',title = 'Cargo Handled',
                           portname = portname,porttype= porttype)
```